# The template is broken -OpenAL.framework--UPDATE--How to create new mac project manually?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, openal, macos

**EDIT: It seems like no one knows the answer. New question: can anyone post a step by step tutorial how to create a mac project manually?? The answer to that question will of course get the "tick" as accepted answer..**

I have the latest cocos2d version installed.

I made a new mac template and without changing anything I just build it. But I get 26 errors and 7 warnings.

The most important one (I think) is this one:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks//OpenAL.framework/OpenAL, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

I get lots of CDSoundEngine and audio stuff errors.

In the warning I copied above...before the "OpenAL.framework" is a double backslash..strange.

I tried to re-add the OpenAL framework but I get the same error.

I also tried to make a new one but I get the same errors..
I also reinstalled cocos2d..didn't work either.

This only happens with the mac templates...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: (Added screenshot)

link to screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3951219/screenshot_mac_template_error.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3951219/screenshot_mac_template_error.png

Comment: How can I create a Mac template manually?

Answer (score 0):

A tad late, but I just had the same problem.

For your original question, try this answer here...

[My OpenAL Framework is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536001/my-openal-framework-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-osx-lion)

Oh, and btw, the // is normal. It happens when a program opens a directory like {Frameworks}/OpenAL.framework, and "Frameworks" is /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/.  The OS takes a // as a /