# My OpenAL framework is broken, how can I fix it? (OSX Lion)

Tags: macos, frameworks, osx-lion, openal

I am developing some game code and it works fine on both windows and mac. Also the sound worked perfectly. I use OpenAL for it.

Recently I installed the OpenAL OSX installer from Creative Labs. It has overwritten my original Apple OpenAL framework and now my project won't compile anymore (linker errors, wrong architecture and stuff like that).

The real question is: can I repair it? Can I find the original Apple OpenAL framework to replace the one on my system? And if not, would someone be so kind to send me the files so that can put them back (if that is even possible)?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling XCode?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Just tried that and as I suspected, this doesn't solve the problem. I think the SDK is installed with the OS not with XCode.

Comment: (can someone tell me what is wrong with my question so that it should get a -1 score?)

Comment: Maybe try using Pacifist (http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract the framework from an OS X installer?

Comment: @andyvn22: I have tried this, but I couldn't find the OpenAL.framework in both the OSX-installer and the XCode-installer. I really think I have used the right tools to search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tried almost everything except for reinstalling the complete os (I reinstalled the lion upgrade, I reinstalled xcode, removed things by hand, ...), I found out that the framework overwritten by the creative installer was the one located in /Library/Frameworks and not the one in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

I thought they were symlinked, but they aren't. So I just copied the one in the 10.7sdk over the one in /Library/Frameworks and everything builds again!

The strangest thing is, that if in my project, I right click on the OpenAL framework in the "Linked frameworks and libraries" list, and I select "Show in Finder", I do get redirected to the sdk, but xcode doesn't seem to use it because when I deleted OpenAL.framework from /Library/Frameworks, xcode showed the framework in red and wouldn't build. So xcode tells me it uses the one in the sdk folder, but is actually using the one in /Library/Frameworks.

I have read on other forums (about other platforms like iPhone and stuff), that people have problems with that. XCode tells them that they are using the framework in the iPhone sdk but actually they are using the one in /Library/Frameworks.

So this must be a bug in xcode.

Anyway... SOLVED!

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Cocos2D/Kobold2D has this problem when compiling for 10.7 too, so I copied the framework from the SDK to the Library, and Cocos/Kobold work great now. I may have broken another app, so I saved the original copy, but that's a problem for another time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the framework to your project. You're including the files so it compiles, but you have to specify which frameworks to link against. It's in /System/Library/Frameworks/.